# What are some high quality Standard ML code/projects to learn from?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to learn to write elegant Standard ML code by reading others' code or projects. Does anyone know of some good code/projects?

Comment: Sorry, seems this is offtopic here.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [MLton](https://github.com/MLton/mlton/) compiler to be a great source for learning the module system.

The [Twelf theorem prover](https://github.com/standardml/twelf) also has a lot of high quality examples.

The [standardml](https://github.com/standardml) github account has a number of projects of varying quality.  Somehow my [sml-ext](https://github.com/standardml/sml-ext) library ended up there.  I'm not sure how.

Comment: +1 for MLton. A great project for learning not only SML, but also compiler organization. The documentation in the wiki describes the high-level overview of the compiler in a very clearly manner.